# How to correctly export Lotus Contact using CSV convertion?

Tags: google, ibm, ibm-domino

I've a little problem (Once again XD).

I currently switching my Mail server from Lotus Domino to Google APPS for business.
Everythings worked fine during the mail migration, but now, I've got to migrate our shared address books to Gapps.

To perform this operation I choose to Export my contacts from the address books using CSV format.

Unfortunatly, I don't now why but Lotus insert some hidden escape characters on my CSV files, then, when I want to import it on Exel they just screw up.

So, my question is, do you have some tricks to repair those messed up export?

When I exported the lotus contacts I choose:

Export ALL
Use UTF-8 characters
Include view title

Do I missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, long story short, I finally found something.

I don't now why but Lotus add some CRLF characters on the file when you perform a CSV export.
Unfortunatly Excel doesn't support them on CSV file (Microsoft's developpers are serial jokers ;-))

I then send my file on my linux, made a little dos2unix cleaning and then remove the rest of the escaped characters which are made by lotus ( ^M for exemple).

So if you have to do something like this one day, think to clean your file before trying to import it ;-)